# Do these two coax amplifiers do the same thing?

Tags: electrical, wiring, coaxial-cable

In the picture below, the one on the left (black) is in use, while the one on the right (red label) is one I found that I'd like to use in another location (to amplify incoming internet signal), so trying to figure out if they do the same exact thing.

It would appear to me the red one has more amplification? (15db?), but are they doing the same thing - amplifying the signal input?

I'm thrown off because the red one says it's for VOIP. I'd like to use it for the same purpose of increasing cable internet signal strength coming into the house, but didn't know if they're functionally doing the same exact thing. Is the VOIP output on the red one the same thing as a normal output?

[image: boxes]

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve? There are a lot of these sort of devices that operate on various parameters, frequencies, gain, etc. each for a specific application.   Decide on what you want and then get the correct devices to accomplish that goal.  Trying to re-use stuff you happen to have laying around probably won't work unless you carefully verify it fits into your plan.

Comment: I have another location I'd like to use one in, so trying to figure out if they do the same exact thing.

Comment: You could spend hours googling specs and analyzing the data....or you could just plug it in and see if it works.   Nothing bad will happen.

Comment: This isn't going to make your internet faster, you know? If your cable internet provider has insufficient signal at your modem it's likely that they'll want to use their own means and their own device.

Comment: The house has numerous splitters and i found that without amplification the signal degrades enough by the time it gets to the modem it results in slower speeds. So another way to say it is, getting the actual internet speed i'm supposed to, not necessarily 'faster'

Answer (score 2):

The VOIP port is meant for the cable company's telephony modem, it works even if the power to the amplifier is interrupted.  The label shows it does not have the same amplification or return loss.

So although it's possible it will work, it isn't the same.